How prevent navigation in React spa when user manually enters page href using react router v6?
We have SPA and use react router v6 for navigation.
I have page with set of restricted urls for each page.
Is there any convenient way block navigation when user manually enter the part of url? For example,: http://localhost:0000/patrol user in address bar change http://localhost:0000/otherway and press enter. Can I prevent this navigation if /otherway is in set of restricted urls for current page?
I try to use beforeunload window event but it does not work stable.
const useBlockNavigation = (restrictedUrls: string[]) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  const [previousLocation, setPreviousLocation] = useState(location.pathname);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkNavigation = (newPath: string) => {
      return restrictedUrls.includes(newPath);
    };

    const handleNavigation = () => {
      const newPath = location.pathname;

      if (checkNavigation(newPath)) {
        navigate(previousLocation); 
      } else {
        setPreviousLocation(newPath);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('popstate', handleNavigation);
    
    const handleBeforeUnload = (event: BeforeUnloadEvent) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.returnValue = '';
    };

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
    
    handleNavigation();
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('popstate', handleNavigation);
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
    };
  }, [location, navigate, restrictedUrls, previousLocation]);
};

const MyComponent = () => {
  const restrictedUrlsForCurrentPage = ['/restricted-page-1', '/restricted-page-2'];
  useBlockNavigation(restrictedUrlsForCurrentPage);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Current Page</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;


Can you clarify what exactly you mean by "restricted URLs"? When the user is manually entering URLs this is a request to the server and the page reloads. The trivial solution is to just not render a Route with a matching path prop. If the client-side router isn't matching "restricted URLs" then nothing is rendered. Please [edit] to clarify the actual issue you have.

I have something like this {pages.length && pages.map((page) => <Route path={page.href} key={page.id} element={<Page {...page} />} />)} and each of those pages has set of restricted hrefs. I need to check what user entered and block or not this navigation.

What does "restricted hrefs" mean? Why do you need to check if a user enters a URL that you don't render a route for? What exactly do you mean by "block navigation"? It's generally considered a UI/UX anti-pattern to block navigation actions. Your question makes no sense so far.

that means that user cannot see Page component with this path

Then don't render a route for paths you don't want to render pages/content for? Are you trying to implement protected routes, e.g. the user needs specific authentication/access/role(s)/etc/whatever to be able to access specific routes your app is rendering?

no, I have something like  {pages.length && pages.map((page) => <Route path={page.href} key={page.id} element={<Page {...page} />} />)}  < Page >  <Child 1 >  <Child 2 />  < /Child 1>  </ Page>. And info about hidden/restricted pages urls is only in Child 2 component. And for each page its different set.

If there is not any Route rendered for "invalid" URL paths then Page and I guess those nested children components also won't be rendered. Ok, so is your question about some issue with conditionally rendering descendent components in Page? Please [edit] to clarify what the exact specific problem is, include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with, and exactly what you are expecting the result/behavior to be.

On pageLoad you could check if a specific (not allowed) url has been entered and redirect to the startpage or some other page:
...
const navigate = useNavigate();
const location = useLocation();

const notAllowedUrls = ['/not', '/allowed', '/urls'];

useEffect(() => {
  const onLoadHandler = () => {
    if (notAllowedUrls.includes(location.pathname)) {
      navigate('/');
    }
  };
  
  window.onload = onLoadHandler;

  return () => {
    window.onload = null;
  };
}, [location, navigate]);
...


it does not work because when user enter new path in address string and submit it, we have new page with location object and its own set of restricted urls
